# Jodit editor i want just the text value from text area I am using react js

Tags: reactjs, frontend, mern, rich-text-editor, jodit

I want to use the Jodit editor to take extract the text, I know it gives html as a output but i need only the text i searched a lot but couldn't find any solution

```
import { Button, Input } from "@chakra-ui/react";
import React, { useRef, useState } from "react";

import JoditEditor from "jodit-react";

function Qinp(props) {
  const [inp, setinp] = useState("");
  const editor = useRef(null);
  

  return (
    <div>
      editor
      
      <JoditEditor ref={editor} />
      
    </div>
  );
}
export default Qinp;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Jodit module to access the function that solves this problem:

```
import { Button, Input } from "@chakra-ui/react";
import React, { useRef, useState } from "react";

import JoditEditor, { Jodit } from "jodit-react";

function Qinp(props) {
  const [inp, setinp] = useState("");
  const [content, setContent] = useState("");
  const editor = useRef(null);
  
  const getTextFromHtml = () => {
    const textOnly = Jodit.modules.Helpers.stripTags(content);
    return textOnly;
  }

  return (
    <div>
      editor
      
      <JoditEditor 
        ref={editor} 
        value={content} 
        onBlur={(newContent) => setContent(newContent)} 
      />
      
    </div>
  );
}
export default Qinp;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can extract only the text through HTML React Parser.

Install it and then import to the file. Later define

```
<JoditEditor 
   ref = {editor} 
   value = {content} 
   config={config} 
   onBlur={newContent => setContent(newContent)} 
   onChange={newContent => {}} 
/> 
<div>HTMLReactParser(content)</div>
```